# Does JpaTokenStore have any downsides when compared to JdbcTokenStore for spring security oauth

Tags: jpa, jdbc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I currently use Jpa via Hibernate in my application. Since spring security oauth2 provides JdbcTokenStore, I started using it. But the problem with that is, I cannot use cache (which all my entities in the application currently share).

It hits the database in a separate flow.

I am thinking implementing **JpaTokenStore** thats backed by Jpa & leverage the cache advantages that comes with it.

Did anyone try implementing this/see any downsides using this approach?

Answer (score 1):

In one project I've implmented `org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.ClientTokenServices` with JPA and didn't notice any problems. I was able to use all standard features of JPA including @Transactional for `JPAClientTokenServices#saveAccessToken`

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing stopping you from doing it, and plenty of people do use JPA for all sorts of things, but IMO JPA is not ideal for handling storage of identity data. JPA is designed and optimized for cacheing data for the duration of a JDBC connection (a transaction basically), while identity data have a typically different and much longer lifetime. If you store long lived data using JPA, you have to deal with the consequences of what happens when you access it outside its normal lifetime, e.g. use DTOs, which ends up negating the benefits of using it in the first place to some extent.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

By "cache advantages that comes with JPA", I was specifically referring to 2nd level cache, not to the transaction level cache. By using additional cache layer such as hazelcast/ehcache, I can avoid the db roundtrip for every secure call (since each secure needs to validate the access token).

I could not fully follow the DTO disadvantages, as the cached AccessToken (irrespective of whether the principal is a DTO/Entity), the access & refresh token cache entry can be invalidated if there are any updates to the underlying user.

Comment: I can also modify the JdbcTokenStore to utilise external cache, but when you have JPA, in most of the cases, user object will be cached for performance reasons most of the times.

So, my view is that it would be better to rely on the user cache that speeds up during the token generation aswell