# JPA TokenStore implementation for OAuth with Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I'm setting up an OAuth 2 authorization server with Spring Boot 2. Examples and existing implementations are all using `JdbcTokenStore` which takes a `DataSource`. I think this is painful and I'm having trouble making the technial dept of using JDBC when I can use JPA.

Are there any existing implementations of a JPA-based `TokenStore`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no implementation of JPA and Spring people don't think they do, this is what one of their gurus (Dr. Dave Syer Senior Consulting Engineer, Pivotal) said in an answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38450863/9428155